# Bootstrap-based vertical tab: alignment issues

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

By using **[Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)** `3.2.0` and a very nice **[snippet](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/simple-vertical-tab)**, I've created a menu-box with multiple choices.
For each menu item there is a label and a short description, as shown in figure below:
[image: IdpSelection menu]

You could find an example with the code on **[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LaBZP/1/)**.

Now, I'd like to:

1. Align menu-item content on middle (regarding the vertical-alignment);
2. Align the submit button on bottom-right.

Someone can suggest me how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Align menu-item content on middle (regarding the vertical-alignment):**

I've recently used this excellent tutorial by @beaver82minimit that allows to create equal height columns bootstrap style: http://www.minimit.com/articles/solutions-tutorials/bootstrap-3-responsive-columns-of-same-height

You can use it like this:

```
<div class="container container-xs-height">
    <div class="row row-xs-height">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-height"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-height col-top"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-height col-middle"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 col-xs-height col-bottom"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With the class `col-middle` you can center your content vertically.

**2. Align the submit button on bottom-right**

a) Add class `bottom-right` to the button and remove the wrapping `<p>`

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn bottom-right" style="margin: 20px 0 0 0;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Submit</button>
```

b) Add this to your stylesheet:

```
.bottom-right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

To prevent tab content to overlap with button, add `padding-bottom` to tab-content div:

```
div.bhoechie-tab-content{
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 54px;
}
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LaBZP/3/

**List-group-item vertical aligning middle:**

```
.text-center {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.text-center > div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Add divs under **list-group-item** to markup:

```
<a href="#" class="list-group-item idp-group-item text-center">
  <div>
    <strong>Label B</strong><br/>Label B Desc
  </div>
</a>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LaBZP/4/

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I'm trying to use col-middle but it still doesn't work on menu items.

Comment: By 'menu-item' do you mean tab contents (PRISMA, Reply, INFN, Sielte)?